# Why python `intA` & `intB` has different memory location when value becomes slightly large?

Tags: python, memory

See below, why `a is b` return `False` when `a = b = 260`?

seems `is` behind the curtain evaluates `id(a) == id(b)`, which represents mem loc of `a` & `b`, but why the mem loc become different?

```py
>>> for i in range(20):
...   a = i * 20
...   b = i * 20
...   print(a is b, a, b, id(a), id(b))

True 0 0 4314981864 4314981864
True 20 20 4314982504 4314982504
True 40 40 4314983144 4314983144
True 60 60 4314983784 4314983784
True 80 80 4314984424 4314984424
True 100 100 4314985064 4314985064
True 120 120 4314985704 4314985704
True 140 140 4314986344 4314986344
True 160 160 4314986984 4314986984
True 180 180 4314987624 4314987624
True 200 200 4314988264 4314988264
True 220 220 4314988904 4314988904
True 240 240 4314989544 4314989544
False 260 260 4308100560 4308100592
False 280 280 4308100176 4308100560
False 300 300 4308100528 4308100176
False 320 320 4308100592 4308100528
False 340 340 4308100560 4308100592
False 360 360 4308100176 4308100560
False 380 380 4308100528 4308100176
```

I expect if `a = b = someIntValue`, then `id(a) == id(b)` should be true, since both points to the same value, which should be stored at the same memory location, regardless of `someIntValue` size

Comment: Python pre-assigns integers objects from -5 to 256. https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html#c.PyLong_FromLong

Answer (score 2):

The reason why id(a) == id(b) returns False when a = b = 260 in your example is due to the way Python manages memory for small integers. In Python, small integers within a certain range are cached and reused. However, as your code demonstrates, this caching isn't universally applicable to all integers.

In your loop, when the integers are in the range of -5 to 256 (inclusive), Python reuses the same memory location for the same integer value, maintaining id(a) == id(b) as True. This is part of an optimization strategy in Python known as "integer interning" to improve memory efficiency for frequently used integers.

Beyond the range of -5 to 256, this caching isn't guaranteed, and Python may create separate objects for the same integer value. In your case, when the loop reaches 260, the id(a) and id(b) are different because the integers are not being cached.

Therefore, in your specific example, the expectation that id(a) == id(b) when a = b = someIntValue applies only within the range of -5 to 256 due to the integer caching optimization Python applies. Once the values exceed this range, new memory locations can be assigned, leading to id(a) != id(b).